# Dummy SSH server?

Tags: ssh, security, software-rec

I'm looking for a dummy SSH server that will simply reject any logins, even if they use the credentials of a real system account. As I search, I'm finding honeypots, but I don't want the hacker to realize they're playing a game. I want them to think they found the actual server, though the "real" SSH server will be running on another port.

Could you point me to some software that accomplishes this?

Even better would be a way to integrate fail2ban so they *really* think they're hitting the actual server!

Edit: I'm running Debian Linux, if that makes a difference.

Comment: So you are trying to setup a honeypot ssh server, but don't want to use the honeypots you have found. Could you elaborate on why they were no good. Eg were they sending a server description prior to failing the authentication that identifies them to potential hackers?  Maybe list the ones you have found so we know not to suggest them.

Comment: also, coming from an engineering perspective at this: what advantage over *not* running the fake SSH server does this have? Do you have a threat scenario that makes it likely an attacker will stop scanning for ports once it finds one? In all threat scenarios I can think of, the opposite would be true: having an SSH server set up on a "guessable" port makes an attacker scan all other ports with higher effort.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I don't want a honeypot. As I understand them, they waste an attacker's resources, but give themselves away that they are indeed a honeypot. Then they know your real server is out there and keep scanning. I don't want them to find the real SSH port. They can brute force all they want to port 22, but they'll get nowhere. That's what I want.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have two Linode instances. One has SSH on port 22 and the other uses a different port > 1024. Looking at the logs, the server with port 22 has put thousands of IP addresses in a fail2ban jail. The other server hasn't had any observable attempts to hack in. It's anecdotal, but it represents my real-world experience. Putting up a fake port 22 SSH instance would de-incentivize further port scanning because they'd stay stuck there, at least that's my opinion.

Comment: @pkSML no that is incorrect. A honeypot (concept) is precisely what you are asking for.  It's a server designed to be the decoy.  The expectation is that if someone should succeed in hacking it, they will not be able to do any damage but it might have silently alerted you to their attempt.  No part of that concept includes telling the attacker it is a honeypot; that would defeat the object.  The only time a honeypot might give itself away is if the attacker actually get's in and discovers they wanted there.  Even then it might not be clear that it was a deliberate honeypot.

Comment: Just a couple of tips though... if you are using a honeypot without some sort of fail2ban then there's not much point, a persistent attacker will port scan regardless. 
 The majority of attackers that might just give up would be fooled simply by moving away from port 22.  So honeypots are much more effective when they trigger a response (blacklisting IPs etc).  Make sure you use private keys and turn off password access to your real ssh server.

Comment: @pkSML I understand what you write about 22 being more "popular", but I honestly fail to see how that would discourage further scanning.

Comment: @PhilipCouling OK. The honeypot I saw on Github would very slooooowwwly spit out a never-ending banner message of random characters. That concept doesn't make a lot of sense to me. And thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a /etc/ssh/sshd_config with:

```
# Fake std port, blocked:
Port 22
# non-std port for real service:
Port 222    
[....]

Match LocalPort 22
      DenyUsers *
```

You will find attempts/rejects in the usual log file and can continue to use tools like fail2ban.

Comment: Wow! So simple yet exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Any ssh server could do this, though would need careful configuration
to never allow a login. Using OpenSSH or whatever would emit the
correct log messages for log scanning software. This would however
complicate the setup of the host; a sysadmin working their 26th hour
of the day might confuse the fake with the real, for example, and
lock out legitimate users, or might misconfigure the fake server to
allow real authentications. Documentation (more work!) may help limit
such problems.

Smart attackers will eventually find the SSH on the different port,
assuming that is exposed directly to the Internet, so this method
probably is not very good against them, especially if they have acquired
real login credentials from some other source. The too many bots
guessing passwords at all the ports will not care; for those a simple
script that presents a SSH login banner and then times out or something
may suffice, but then you waste more CPU and some network bandwidth on
your end over simply blocking TCP/22 and moving around the port the real
SSH server runs at (again, assuming it is directly availalble, and not
behind a VPN or some other layer). The simple server had better not have
any security vulnerabilities in it, and probably should not waste too
much CPU, nor consume too many sockets. It might look something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
# fakesshd - present a banner and not much else (we hope)

set listenport 2222
set message SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
set close_milliseconds 9999

# if on OpenBSD, https://github.com/thrig/tcl-pledge
#package require pledge
#pledge {dns inet stdio} NULL

proc banner {socket clientaddr clientport} {
    global close_milliseconds message
    puts $socket $message
    flush $socket
    after $close_milliseconds close $socket
}

socket -server banner $listenport
vwait the_heat_death_of_the_universe
```

However, regular users or monitoring systems might connect to the wrong
SSH port and then perhaps get their IP address into blacklists or IP
reputation systems. That is probably not a good outcome. The overworked
sysadmin might also connect to the wrong port and then waste time trying
to debug why that is failing, in addition to whatever else they do need
to work on.

So, dumb bots don't care (just firewall them off?), smart attackers will
find the real port (more work for you to move the port around, or put it
behind a VPN) or won't care if they find some other hole in your
security ("hi, this is Bob with IT, could you tell me your SSH
configuration, we're having an audit"), and the setup makes life for the
sysadmin and possibly also the users more difficult. Not seeing much if
any plusses here.

Comment: I'm the sole maintainer of the system, so nobody else to worry about. Thanks for your solution!